# Return an object with properties from function parameter list

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a function that constructs and returns an object with properties that match the array of strings passed in the params.

```
type Foods = 'apple' | 'banana' | 'pear';

function foodObjects<K extends Foods>(foods: Foods[]): Record<K, number> {
    const ret = {};
    foods.forEach((food, i) => {
        ret[food] = i;
    })
    return ret;
}

foodObjects(['apple', banana']); // should return { apple: 0, banana: 1 }
```

In this simple example, you pass it an array of fruits and it returns an object with the fruit names as keys. However, I get a warning when defining the `ret` variable (`const ret = {};`):

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Record<K, number>'

I can resolve that error with the `as` keyword, but this doesn't feel correct:

```
const ret = {} as Record<K, number>;
```

Comment: Nitpick: The type describes a value that holds an apple, a banana, or a pear, not a collection of them. So it should be singular: "type Food`.

Comment: FYI, you are reinventing reduce()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array to turn into an object, your best bet is to reduce it:

```
type Foods = "apple" | "banana" | "pear";

function foodObjects<K extends Foods>(foods: Foods[]): Record<K, number> {
  return foods.reduce((acc, food, i) => ({ ...acc, [food]: i }), <Record<K, number>>{});
}

console.log(foodObjects(["apple", "banana"])); // should return { apple: 0, banana: 1 }
```

Since it was pointed out that casting is not super ideal, here is a version that does not need casting:

```
type Foods = "apple" | "banana" | "pear";

type FoodObjects = {
  [K in Foods]: number;
};

function foodObjects(foods: Foods[]): FoodObjects {
  const entries = foods.map((food, i) => [food, i]);
  return Object.fromEntries(entries);
}
```

Comment: `Array.reduce` is the standard approach, even though It's still a bit of a hack, because of that casting. Btw, I think the modern syntax is `{} as Record<K, number>`.

Comment: Provided an alternative too